# OutOfMemoryException with Stream Processing

Tags: scala, stream

I wrote a function that, given a `Stream[Long]`, it will filter out numbers > 4,000,000.

```
  def filterLt4Mil(xs: Stream[Long]) = {
    @tailrec
    def go(xs: Stream[Long], acc: Stream[Long]): Stream[Long] = xs match {
      case Stream() => acc
      case a #:: as if(a < 4000000L) => go(as, acc :+ a)
      case a #:: as if(a > 4000000L) => go(as, acc)
    }
    go(xs, Stream[Long]())
  }
```

However, I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException` when passing in a Stream ranging from 0 to 10,000,000 million.

```
scala> val x = Stream.range(0,10000000L)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Long] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> filterLt4Mil(x)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.toStream(List.scala:312)
```

Since `filterLt4Mil` uses the tail-call optimization, my understanding is that the stack should not overflow.

However, why is this `OutOfMemoryException` occurring? How can I prevent it?

Comment: what happens if you leave out the val x = line (ie, write it as filterLt4Mil(Stream.range(0,10000000L))?

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some issues.

Your `go` function has the effect of reversing the elements in the output stream, since you are appending to the end of the accumulator.

Additionally, the act of appending, rather than prepending, causes the entire accumulator to be materialized into a List, which then gets copied at each step in the iteration. This is what is causing the OutOfMemoryError, since your implementation requires quadratic memory.

Furthermore, your `match` block is not exhaustive, since you do not handle the case of `a == 4000000L`.

If all you want to do is filter out elements greater than 4000000, this will suffice:

```
xs filterNot {_ > 4000000L}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on quadratic memory?

Comment: You're copying the entire accumulator at each iteration, which means the memory consumed is the number of elements in the stream multiplied by the size of the accumulator, which, on average, is half the size of the stream, which means you are consuming 1/2 of the square of the stream size in memory. This gets periodically garbage collected, since you throw away the old copies after each iteration, but for large streams, the JVM ends up spending too much time on garbage collection and gives up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is already a `filter` method for streams, but I guess you wanted to do it yourself.

Streams have a strict head and a lazy tail. Calling `Stream.range(0,10000000L)` will only have the `0` in memory, since the rest will be lazily evaluated.

BUT in your `filterLt4Mil` method you iterate over the whole stream, causing all elements in this stream to be evaluated, resulting in all numbers from `0` to `10000000L` to be stored in memory...
Storing such an amount can cause the `OutOfMemoryException`.

For example: `x.forall(_ >= 0)` also results in an `OutOfMemoryException`, `forall` also has to traverse the entire stream while `_ >= 0` is satisfied.

You would want your `filter` method to be applied lazily. Have a look at the source code. Might give you an idea to how it works:
(http://harrah.github.io/browse/samples/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala.html)

```
override final def filter(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = {
  // optimization: drop leading prefix of elems for which f returns false
  var rest = this dropWhile (!p(_))
  if (rest.isEmpty) Stream.Empty
  else new Stream.Cons(rest.head, rest.tail filter p)
}
```

And one more problematic thing about your code. Since it has to traverse the entire stream, you can guess what happens with infinite streams.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not blowing the stack - looks like you're running out of heap (to confirm, switch to using Int(s) instead of Long(s)). The scala compiler should know how to tail-recurse optimize this function.

10m longs is 64m. If you're creating 10m instances of a 64m list, you're in trouble.

Also, you'll probably want to have lazy streams, not just tail recursion, for this function to be memory optimized. 64m isn't that big by itself tough, so this optimization is probably not required.

The way I see it, you're either creating 10m copies of your XS parameter, or of your ACC one.

to me, the xs: parameter seems lazy; but you're keeping a reference to it from outside your function, and streams are memoizers in scala.

so i would bet on that parameter being the one you're getting millions of copies of (ie, the scala compiler doesn't know to let go of the intermediate values of). the other argument should get garbage collected on each call (or, since we're talking tail recursion, get optimized to one, 64m long, in memory list)